# Como fazer o navegador nâo salvar login e senha quando não é um formulário de login?

Tags: html, html5

Tenho uma página de confirmação de cadastro que é onde o usuário cria sua senha e algumas outras informações. Uma dessas outras informaçōes é o telefone, que vem logo antes do campo de senha.

Os navegadores estavam preenchendo automaticamente o campo de telefone com logins já salvos e o campo de senha com a respectiva senha para esse login, e também perguntando se eu queria salvar aquelas informaçōes, novamente com o telefone no lugar do login. Eu consegui corrigir o autofill usando o `autocomplete="new-password"` no campo de senha, mas ao contrario do que eu imaginei isso não corrigiu o segundo problema.

Depois disso lembrei que o campo de telefone estava com `autocomplete=off`, e só pra testar resolvi tirar. Isso acabou resolvendo o segundo problema no Chrome (não sei por que), mas no Firefox não.

Alguma solução ou explicação?

Comment: autocomplete aceita apenas valor off ou on

Comment: eu normalmente ponho um campo hidden de password antes do verdadeiro (quando tem mais de um, tem browser que desativa o autofill), e randomizo os "name"

Comment: @Ivcs o autocomplete aceita alguns outros valores além de on e off https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete

Comment: @bacco obrigado pela dica, mas eu não queria fazer isso por que me parece gambiarra. Não acredito que não tenha um jeito "certo" pra fazer isso

Comment: Com o tempo vc vai perceber que fazer coisa legal pra web precisa de uns 30% de gambiarra. Os comitês que regulam essas coisas são de teóricos de mil outros ramos, por isso CSS e JS são tão mal projetados, e o XHTML perdeu pro HTML na escolha dos padrões futuros. Comitê geralmente tem muito cacique pra pouco índio. É por isso que mesmo o mercado insistindo, os sistemas desktop bem feitos são sempre muito superiores aos sistemas web bem feitos. Aposto que nos próximos 5 a 10 anos vai continuar sendo. Hà 8 anos mais ou menos eu falava isso, e diziam que eu tava por fora. Hoje dou risada deles :)

Comment: Em outras palavras, sei como vc se sente por uma coisa tão simples não ter uma solução óbvia. Sinto isso o tempo todo quando faço coisa pra web, e poderia dizer uma lista delas, pra falar a verdade. Mas acho ótimo que você esteja buscando por um caminho "certo". Esteja preparado pra não encontrar, mas nunca deixe de procurar. Volta e meia os caras dão uma dentro e melhoram algo com o tempo.

Comment: Sim, é bem triste não ter uma solução simples pra problemas tão pequenos. Mas com a comunidade de desenvolvedores cada vez mais participativa talvez isso mude um dia. Espero que sim haha